# Prevent UIWebView in full screen to rotate

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, rotation

I have an UIWebView that might show a YouTube video, so when it happens it goes full screen. My app doesn't rotates, but the UIWebView rotates, so if i stop watching it in landscape mode, when i return to my screen it goes berserk.

How can i listen for when the user taps done or to directly avoid the UIWebView to rotate?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We regularly have portrait-only apps that show landscape videos via web views.

Are you sure you're returning NO for landscape orientations from your shouldAutorotateToOrientation: method of the top view controller? When you say "goes berserk," what do you mean? One thing I've found is that setting the main window's `rootViewController` property (rather than just adding your root view controller's view as a subview of the window view) can cause trouble when returning from videos like this.

Comment: I'm returning (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) in shouldAutorotate and it happens in both cases: if i add the subview or if i set the rootViewController. What happens is that when i rotate the video, the view also rotates. And it does although no viewController has shouldAutorotate yes and the target supports only portrait.

Comment: Forgot to mention it, this happens in iOS5. In iOS4, the video doesn't rotates

Comment: Are you doing anything with rotation notifications anywhere in the app?

Comment: I've just tried this on an iOS 5 device, and it works fine for me. In both iOS 5 and iOS 4, tapping the youtube link brings up the video in landscape. When tapping done, the video slides away, revealing the view controller in portrait. Are you testing device or status bar orientation anywhere?

Comment: I'm starting to go crazy. Once the video starts, and if i rotate the device, the view rotates. And if i put a will/didRotate, they doesn't get called. But afterwards, once everything happens they start receiving the notifications. And nowhere in my app i allow anything to rotate, it only happens in iOS5, when the UIWebView gets full screen.

Comment: Well, turns out the thing was the UINavigationController. Never had to, but now, in iOS5 in order to prevent the UIWebView from rotating and although every UIViewController wasn't supposed to rotate, i had to set shouldAutoRotate to NO in the UINavigationController itself, via a category. The rootController was the navigationController, but don't know why now this needs to be done.

Comment: You probably want to subclass UINavigationController instead of using a category. Are you sure that your top level controller was being presented by the navigation controller normally?

Comment: Thanks for the advise, i was planning to make it a subclass (it was easier to try a category). The top level controller was being presented normally, no problem whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm a few months late, but I've written a simple `UINavigationController` subclass to properly pass the `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation`, `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation`, and `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation` calls through to the proper view controller.

Hope this helps :)

https://gist.github.com/bbae6291c4f6bf05d1eb

Answer (score 0):

The method `viewWillAppear:` in your `UIViewController` will be called when the video is closed from full screen. You can adjust the view there by calling `setNeedsDisplay` on your `UIView`